# Calculating standard deviation without a data set.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

I know how to calculate SD when given data points by using: $ \displaystyle \mathrm{SD} = \sqrt{\sum(x^2 - \text{mean}^2) / n} $.

I have been given just the sum of $x$ and sum of $x^2$. How do I calculate SD from this?!

An example question I am stuck on:
Sum of $x = 1303$

Sum of $x^2 = 123557.$

There are 14 years for which the data is given - I would assume this is n...

Comment: would you like to describe how do you compute SD given data points? which formula do you use?

Comment: Hint: The variance is $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}(Q - T^2/n),$ where $Q = \sum_i X_i^2$ and $T = \sum_i X_i.$ This is proved by performing the square in $\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_i(X_i - \bar X)^2,$ using the distributive law, and using the definition of $\bar X.$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You need a formula, where you can enter the *sum of squares* and the *square of the sum*. Let us first define these as follows:
$$
SSQ =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k^2 \quad\text{and}\quad SQS = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k \;.
$$

A famous formula of the (population)<sup>1</sup> variance is
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X)
= \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k^2 - \left( \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k \right)^2 = \dfrac{SSQ}{n} - \left( \dfrac{SQS}{n} \right)^2 \;.
$$
The (population) standard deviation, therefore, is
$$
\boxed
{
  \mathrm{SD}(X)
  = \sqrt{\dfrac{SSQ}{n} - \left( \dfrac{SQS}{n} \right)^2}
} \;.
$$
You see that you also need $n$, the number of samples.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The population statistics can be [corrected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction), when sample statistics are required.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In a not confusing manner (hopefully) the way i would start is to work out the variance using:
Sxx = (Sum of)x^2 - n(Mean)^2

Then from there to find the standard deviation i would use:

srqroot(Sxx/n-1)

hopefully that has helped!

Comment: Your formula for SD seems slightly wrong.  Assuming the mean $m$ is known then the variance $V=\frac{\sum (x_k-m)^2}{n}=\frac{\sum x_k^2}{n}-m^2$ so $SD=\sqrt{\frac{\sum x_k^2}{n}-m^2}$.  When the mean is being estimated by the average of the $x's$, then the division is by $n-1$ rather than $n$.